# InApp Purchase rejected in App Store

Tags: iphone, app-store, in-app-purchase

I just got rejected on my Free app from app store. I uploaded 3 apps, HD(iPad), PayedIphone and freeiphone. In the free-version I had a link to the fullversion.
Apparently I need inAppPurchase in the free-version rather than linking to the fullversion.

How should I implement this in the easiest way? All I want is a button that says Buy full version and then the free-version becomes the full version. Is it possible to use just those two or do i need to create another full version for this purpose.

I have no idea how to make the inAppPurchase except the tutorials Google give me, any recommendations or example code I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working after watching this tutorial on u-tube. I can really recommend it.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xGDGO5P95Dg

Answer (score 5):

I found this site very helpful in setting up an in-App purchase:

http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/

Answer (score 0):

No way.  The proper way to do that is to include all the functionality of the fill version in the free version and only unlock those functionalities whenever the user buy your inApp purchase item.

start by **attentively** (details really matters when inApp purchase is concerned) reading  the inApp purchase developer guide at developer.apple.com

Comment: That's actually already done! The free version contains all the functionality. So i should have a variable that indicates if the app has been bought or not? Depending on that variable add or lock functionality? The variable has to be saved in memory between programstarts aswell i guess, NSUserDefaults is ok?

Comment: you can either put in userdefaults . The best one to use is the nsuserdefaults if its just a single variable

Answer (score 0):

All you need is this:  http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-%E2%80%93-in-app-purchases/

By far the easiest In-App storekit to implement... He walks you through the whole thing and then there is a link at the bottom with the source code zip file.  Make sure you read it and get a good understanding. **Rule of thumb:** Never implement any one else's source code without understanding it first.  You will save yourself a lot of headaches with debugging later.

Remember though:  Now you have to build in a network check to see if a network exists prior to them clicking the "upgrade" button or else your app will get rejected once again.  Luckily, I have just the thing for you:  [How to check for an active Internet connection on iOS or OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083701/how-to-check-for-an-active-internet-connection-on-iphone-sdk/3597085#3597085)

Also, I agree that `NSUserDefaults` are the best way to go, and luckily that source code link above does all of that for you!  It seriously doesn't get any easier.  [Props to this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/90165/mugunth-kumar)

Answer (score 0):

There is a sample project here..

http://www.theapptree.com/samples