# iPhone Lite to Paid App

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, app-store, in-app-purchase

I have a lite iPhone app that has a link for the Paid app on the app Store.
On the following question it was mentioned that the app was rejected because of the same behavior and in order to apply this I have to use In app purchase instead. 
I have seen Lite and Paid apps on the store.
I wanted to know how I can handle the link between the two apps without being rejected. I would appreciate your help. 
Thanks,

[InApp Purchase rejected in App Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776721/inapp-purchase-help-needed)

Comment: It should be just fine to link to the paid app within your app. I had a app a while ago that was like that and didn't have any troubles.

Answer (score 1):

My app DreamFX lite was just approved today. it has a full version (dreamfx photo) and a lite version (dreamfx lite) the lite version just links to the app store to purchase the full version. I didn't do anything special with in app purchases, so I'm not sure why exactly the poster you linked to was reporting his app got rejected.

Comment: My experience predates the existence of in-app purchasing, but I did get a rejection because I had a link to the app store but Apple didn't feel I'd made it explicit that the user was being asked to go and buy something. It's not impossible that Joakim, of the other StackOverflow question, misunderstood what Apple had said — it could have been something along the lines of "you don't make it explicit that this is a link out to buy from the app store, using an in-app purchase would be an acceptable solution".